# how to write a code for return an integer value in java with various cases like if condition

Tags: java

There are 3 integers i.e. a=5 , b=10, c=5. So if all are same then it returns 0. If  any 2 are same then it returns 1. If no one is same the it should return 2.

```
public class Return {

    int decide(int a, int b, int c) {
        if(a==b && b==c) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(a==b||a==c||b==c) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(a!=b && a!=c && b!=c) {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Return().decide(5,10,15);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You just need to write some conditions, show your effort and code.

Comment: @Ruslan i edited my question. kindly please help.

Comment: @LuCio I added my code which i done till now. kindly help me

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar looks like your code is working as expected. What the issue?

Comment: @Ruslan i am not getting any output. It shows blank.

Comment: @PrashantTendulkar you probably want to print the output. `new Return().decide(5,10,15);` this line returns the result, but you ignore it. Try to wrap it into `System.out.println`

Comment: Instead of printing the result consider writing a [unit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). Have you heard about [Test driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)?

Comment: @Ruslan 'System.out.println(new Return().decide(2, 10, 2));' Thank you so much

Comment: @LuCio no i didn't heard about Test driven Development. I will surely go through it.

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing the existing one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an output just sub your last line of code with this one:

```
System.out.print(new Return().decide(5,10,15));
```